# Include items from one array of objects as array in each object of second array of objects (by key)

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to merge two arrays of objects in a very specific way. I know I can use maps, sets, spread or simple for loops to combine the arrays together. However, what I am after is not exactly a "typical merge".

Given the following two arrays :

```js
// Array containing the list of cars being assembled in the factory (1 object per vehicle)
carList = [
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Escape'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    make: 'Honda',
    model: 'Civic'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '999',
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model S'
  }
]

// Array containing each section for each car (by nature, this array will be much larger
// than the one above since we have many sections to assemble per vehicle (for example :
// wheels, doors, windows, seats, etc.). I only included a few for this example)
assemblyProgress = [
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    section: 'Passenger Door',
    status: 'Completed'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    section: 'Driver Door',
    status: 'In WIP'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    section: 'Passenger Door',
    status: 'Not Started'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    section: 'Driver Door',
    status: 'Not Started'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '789',
    section: 'Driver Door',
    status: 'Completed'
  }
]
```

Note that I may have cars in the "carList" array that do not have entries in the "assemblyProgress" array and/or entries in the "assemblyProgress" array for cars that do not exist in the "carList" array yet. Only information relevant to cars found in the "carList" array should be included in the resulting array. I want to end up with something similar to the "carList" array but add an "assemblyProgress" array in each car's object tree containing the corresponding data from the second array. Ultimately, what I would like to end up with is the following array :

```js
resultingArray = [
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Escape',
    assemblyProgress: [
      {
        section: 'Passenger Door',
        status: 'Completed'
      },
      {
        section: 'Driver Door',
        status: 'In WIP'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    make: 'Honda',
    model: 'Civic',
    assemblyProgress: [
      {
        section: 'Driver Door',
        status: 'Not Started'
      },
      {
        section: 'Driver Door',
        status: 'Not Started'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '999',
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model S'
    assemblyStatus: []
  }
]
```

Also note that unfortunately I have no control over the arrays' design/structure as they are pulled from an SQL server.

What I have so far is the following but what it does is add the car's info for each entry of the "assemblyProgress" array, which is not the desired result :

```js
const resultingArray = this.assemblyProgress.map(t1 => ({...t1, ...this.carList.find(t2 => t2.vehicleSerialNumber === t1.vehicleSerialNumber)}));
```

Here is the StackBlitz corresponding to what I have so far :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a9nxav?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array.filter():

```js
const carList = [
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Escape'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    make: 'Honda',
    model: 'Civic'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '999',
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model S'
  }
]

// Array containing each section for each car (by nature, this array will be much larger
// than the one above since we have many sections to assemble per vehicle (for example :
// wheels, doors, windows, seats, etc.). I only included a few for this example)
const assemblyProgress = [
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    section: 'Passenger Door',
    status: 'Completed'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '123',
    section: 'Driver Door',
    status: 'In WIP'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    section: 'Passenger Door',
    status: 'Not Started'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '456',
    section: 'Driver Door',
    status: 'Not Started'
  },
  {
    vehicleSerialNumber: '789',
    section: 'Driver Door',
    status: 'Completed'
  }
]

const resultingList = carList.map(car=>({...car,assemblyProgress:assemblyProgress.filter(asm=>asm.vehicleSerialNumber===car.vehicleSerialNumber)}))

console.log(resultingList);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.